# How to properly position text on screen using CSS to fit for multiples mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show a modal with biography info after doing clic on a person photograph. I cannot fit properly the position of the text on screen using CSS to fit for multiples mobile devices.
I am using a image that have the photo and the logo included in the same image. I thought it would be easier in this way but maybe is not the best way.

It's seems jsfiddle is not working.
https://jsfiddle.net/L6jo0drh/

[image]

```
/*HTML*/

<div style="width: 260px;margin: auto;">
<figure class="item">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/260x260/000/fff" width="200" class="trigger trigger_1"/>
    <figcaption class="caption"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span><br>
CPHC</figcaption>
</figure></div>

<div class="modal modal_1">
    <div class="modal-content modal-content_1">
        <span class="close-button close-button_1">×</span>
        <picture>
        <source media="(orientation: landscape)" srcset="hhttps://dummyimage.com/1200x768/000/fff">
        <source media="(orientation: portrait)" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/465x800/000/fff">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x768/000/fff" width="100%" height="auto">
        </picture>
        <div class="bio_header">
            <span class="nombre_bio"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</strong></span><br/>
            <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</strong><br/>
            <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</strong><br/>
            <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</strong><br/>
            <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</strong><br/>
            <a href="https://link">https://link</a>
        <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="bio_body">
            <p class="p_bio">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat. At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

/*JS*/

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    /* Modal 1 */
    const modal_1 = document.querySelector(".modal_1");
    const trigger_1 = document.querySelector(".trigger_1");
    const closeButton_1 = document.querySelector(".close-button_1");

    function toggleModal_1() {
        modal_1.classList.toggle("show-modal_1");
        if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
             modal_1.classList.toggle("modal_mobile");
        }
        else
        {
            modal_1.classList.toggle("modal_desktop");
        }
    }

    function windowOnClick_1(event_1) {
        if (event_1.target === modal_1) {
            toggleModal_1();
        }
    }

    trigger_1.addEventListener("click", toggleModal_1);
    closeButton_1.addEventListener("click", toggleModal_1);
    window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick_1);
});

/*CSS*/

.modal {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.trigger {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    /*width: 24rem;*/
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.close-button {
    float: right;
    width: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.close-button:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
}

.show-modal_1 {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}

.show-modal_2 {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}

.show-modal_3 {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
}

@media handheld and (orientation: landscape) {
    .show-modal_1 {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    .show-modal_2 {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    .show-modal_3 {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    .modal {
        position: fixed;
        left: 25%;
        top: 50%;
        margin: -150px 0 -150px 0;
        width: 900px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        transform: scale(2.2);
        transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
}

@media handheld and (orientation: portrait) {
    .show-modal_1 {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        width: 24rem;
    }
    .show-modal_2 {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        width: 24rem;
    }
    .show-modal_3 {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        width: 24rem;
    }
    .modal {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        transform: scale(2.2);
        transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
}

.image_bio {
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

.modal_desktop {
        position: fixed;
        left: 25%;
        top: 50%;
        margin: -150px 0 -150px 0;
        width: 900px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        transform: scale(2.2);
        transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

.modal_mobile {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        transform: scale(2.2);
        transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The content is quite long and it won't fit most screens. So, you will need to overflow the content and add a scroll to it. Modify your following classes and you will get the desired result:

```
.modal_desktop {
    position: fixed;
    left: 25%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -150px 0 -150px 0;
    width: 780px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transform: scale(2.2);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.modal-content {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   background-color: white;
   padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
   border-radius: 0.5rem;
   z-index: 1000;
   height: 50%;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```